# Snotty, snooty, haughty

Tags: meaning, synonyms

There must be a subtle difference between the terms 'snotty', 'snooty', and 'haughty'. The dictionaries have barely different definitions:

To choose one, Merriam-Webster gives:

- [snotty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snotty) : 1 - soiled with nasal mucus a snotty nose, 2 : annoyingly or spitefully unpleasant; especially : **snooty**
- [snooty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snooty) : 1 - looking down the nose : showing disdain, 2 : characterized by snobbery
- [haughty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haughty) : blatantly and disdainfully proud : having or showing an attitude of superiority and contempt for people or things perceived to be inferior, haughty aristocrats

(ignoring the literal snot version of 'snotty')

Following all the vocabulary in those definitions, disdain, snobbery, inferior, contempt, proud, nose(?), there may well be things that differentiate these terms but it is not at all clear from the descriptions.

What exactly are the nuances that differentiate these?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of children can be snotty (= bratty, or roughly "disrespectful to adult authority"), whereas children generally wouldn't be haughty or snooty unless their family was rich or high-class.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what your definitions and Mr Church said, but to put a finer point on it:

## [Haughty](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84614),

1st attested in the 1530s, is literally just the French word for *high* with a *y* tacked onto the end. Hence,

> High in one's own estimation; lofty and disdainful in feeling or [demeanor]; proud, arrogant, supercilious.

## [Snotty](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183469),

1st attested with the sense (haughtily if not snottily mislabeled as *dialect* or *slang* by the *OED*)

> Angry, curt, short-tempered; pert, saucy, impudent; proud, conceited. Now *esp*. supercilious, aloof, ‘snooty’.

in the 1870s as a more specific variation of its sense `Dirty, mean, paltry, contemptible`, first attested in the 1680s as a synonym of the same era's "snotty-nosed", today's "snot-nosed".

## [Snooty](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183418),

the most recent word, showed up by the 1910s as a dialectical version of *snout* (=*nose*) + *y* to describe people with their nose in the air around their presumed inferiors:

> Supercilious, haughty, conceited; affecting superiority, snobbish; ‘highbrow’, ‘stuck-up’. Occasionally, irritable, short-tempered.

So, in short, **all of them *can* simply mean supercilious** but there are different connotations and social registers for them.

- Haughty is used for someone who thinks the world of themself (possibly justified!);
- snotty is used for someone who feels the same way but in a childish, petty, and contemptible way; and
- snooty is used for someone who feels the same way but more because of their disdain for others (esp. the lower classes).

Comment: A shorthand at this moment in history: in media portrayals, Obama was often *haughty*; Trump's tweets are often *snotty*; and European bureaucrats obliged to meet with Trump (or their own citizenry) are often *snooty*. They're mostly pejoratives, but if you're from their teams you tend to feel their high self-esteem or derision of others is justifiable. Still a bit different.

Comment: Alternatively, in *Game of Thrones*, Stannis Baratheon, Tywin Lannister, and Drogo were haughty; the Imp was often snotty in an amusing way; the old High Septon was snotty in an offputting way; and the Qarthians were snooty.